# Using an aggregated entity query to find duplicate taxonomy terms

Tags: 8, entities, database

Due to a content migration bug, there are nodes in our site that reference the same taxonomy term multiple times with different deltas:

```
bundle  deleted entity_id   revision_id langcode    delta   field_term_target_id
article 0   1061    1062    en  0   307
article 0   1061    1062    en  1   307
```

I can find these with the following database query

```
SELECT
    entity_id, field_term_target_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM node__field_industries
GROUP BY entity_id, field_industries_target_id
HAVING count > 1;
```

For building a tool that lists these nodes within Drupal, I would like to use an entity query instead of accessing the database directly.

I've tried the following:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->getAggregateQuery()
  ->groupBy('nid')
  ->groupBy('field_industries')
  ->aggregate('field_industries.delta', 'COUNT')
  ->conditionAggregate('field_industries.delta', 'COUNT', 1, '>')
  ->execute();
```

But this results in an error `Invalid specifier 'delta'`. If I aggregate on 'field_industries' instead (which seems wrong, as I'm already grouping on that value), I get completely wrong results back (specifically, vastly inflated values for COUNT, which can be as high as 16 even for nodes that are not affected by the bug).

So I guess my question is: How do I aggregate on a non-default column in the field table (such as the `delta` column)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Database abstraction layer:

```
$connection = Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->select('node__field_industries', 'i');
$query->fields('i', ['entity_id', 'field_term_target_id']);
$query->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'count');
$query->groupBy('i.entity_id');
$query->groupBy('i.field_term_target_id');
$query->having('COUNT(*) > 1');

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The question is to use "an aggregated entity query", that is not an entity query.

Comment: Then give a better alternative instead of down voting. The above answer does what OP asks.

Comment: It is not an ENTITY query, it is a DATABASE query. I was looking for information on how to aggregate entity queries, the answer was not helpful. But yes you are right, I should have provided a better answer.